# Android ViewBinding - No Getters for Views

Tags: java, android, android-viewbinding

I am just working on my first test app with view binding.

The examples in the Android docs indicate if I have a view with the ID "txt_name", the view would be accessible from the generated class as

```
binding.getTxtName()
```

However, it appears the members are public and are accessed this way

```
binding.txtName
```

That is fine but just not my preferential style of coding.

Is there a way to change the behaviour so getters are generated by the view binding framework?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using data binding? As far as I am aware, view binding generates getters whilst data binding just generates fields.

Comment: @HenryTwist I don't get any getters for the views in my binding classes when using `viewBinding`. However, all those fields are `final`, so I can imagine that Google didn't see any point in adding getters for them.

Comment: That's strange because the documentation specifically mentions getters, for example here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities. I actually haven't used view binding for a while, I'll have a double check to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah, `getRoot` exists, if that's what you're referring to. That's because it overrides a method in the `ViewBinding` interface. I'm guessing `binding.getName()` might be a copy-paste error, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Yes I was referring to where it says `binding.getName().setText(viewModel.getName());`. However I've just tested it and it does only generate fields, so probably just a typo. It does seem strange that they wouldn't follow Java conventions.